# Young adult fantasy novel where the main character has a talisman

Tags: story-identification, novel, young-adult

Looking for a book I read in high school between 2002 and 2006 about a group of teenagers that get teleported/summon to another world with magic. The main character had a talisman that I think made forcefields, his love interest use ice magic, one could turn invisible (I think), and one was strong.

The other thing I can remember that one of the side character was a dwarf in mustard clothing. He turns out to be some sort of magician important to the storyline.

The book had a drawing of the party and looked very dungeons and dragon.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  We don't know when you were in high school, so approximately what year was this?

Comment: I was in high school in 2002-2006.